Getting 401 unauthorised when trying to access JWT authenticated page in Django even after generating token
I'm a student trying to teach myself JWT authentication. I created a basic log in page and after logging in the user should see a welcome page that says Welcome {username}.
However even after logging in, the welcome page says
Welcome
GET /welcome/
HTTP 401 Unauthorized
Allow: GET, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="api"
{
"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
}
My code looks like this:
views.py
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from loginapp.models import User
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, permission_classes, authentication_classes
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication import JWTAuthentication
from django.urls import reverse


def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        print("Username:", username)
        print("Password:", password)
        user = User.objects.filter(username=username).first()
        #user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None and user.password == password:
            refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
            token = str(refresh.access_token)
            response = JsonResponse({'message': 'Login successful'})
            response['Authorization'] = f'Bearer {token}'
            return response
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'error_message': 'Invalid username or password.'}, status=400)
    else:
        return render(request, 'login.html')

@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def welcome(request):
    username = request.user.username
    return Response({'message': f'Welcome, {username}!'})


my urls.py looks like this:
from django.urls import path
from loginapp import views
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenRefreshView


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.login, name='login'),
    path('welcome/',views.welcome, name='welcome'),
    #path('welcome/<str:username>/', views.welcome, name='welcome'),
    path('token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
]

my login.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <div id="error-message"></div>
    <form id="loginForm">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username"><br>
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password"><br>
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>

    <script>
        document.getElementById("loginForm").addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            
            fetch("/", {
                method: "POST",
                body: new FormData(document.getElementById("loginForm"))
            })
            .then(response => {
                if (response.ok) {
                    const token = response.headers.get('Authorization').split(' ')[1];
                    localStorage.setItem("jwtToken", token);
                    window.location.href = "/welcome";
                } else {
                    return response.json();
                }
            })
            .then(data => {
                if (data.error_message) {
                    document.getElementById("error-message").innerText = data.error_message;
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error("Error:", error);
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>

my settings.py:
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ),
}

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=60),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
    'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': True,
    'BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION': True,
    'UPDATE_LAST_LOGIN': True,
}

Could anyone please pinpoint where the issue might be arising?
I'm using a MySQL database which is where I'm querying the username from.
I've tried changing settings.py  ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME but even that is 60 minutes now and the error still persists.

You returned JsonResponse with access token inside it, but after that you have to manually add token value into your next request header.
response = JsonResponse({'message': 'Login successful'})
response['Authorization'] = f'Bearer {token}'
return response

This code won't work properly since each request and response are regarded as independent. Your next request will not contain authorization token, which causes 401 Unauthorized error.
What I recommend is to return access token only without setting Authorization key for response.
return JsonResponse({'message': 'Login successful', 'token': token})

And you can use this token by saving it on cookie or local storage in frontend.

Thank you! I've tried returning just the token as a response and saving it on local storage in frontend. However the 401 error persists. I've tried debugging it by adding print statements in the js portion of the code, and I'm able to see the token in the console so it is being validated but I'm unable to see the header which I believe is causing this issue.

As cookie data in browser automatically included to header while sending request to server, local storage does not. You also have to read token data from local storage and add to header manually on your frontend side.
